# Include External Source Code Library for Android Studio 1.4.1

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, module, mapbox

I'm attempting to create an Android app with Android Studio that uses source code from:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/

I will need to modify the source code, build and debug the changes, and commit those changes back to the forked repository I've made from mapbox-gl-native.

It appears much of the library code is in C++, while the project that uses the code will be in Java (if that makes a difference).

I've tried a bunch of things (mostly ignorant) and keep getting the following message:

Gradle 'name' project refresh failed
Error: Configuration with name 'default' not found.

Newbie on Android Studio, so please be as descriptive as possible. I'm using Android Studio 1.4.1, as other similar questions seem to have version specific answers.

Is there a description on how to set up an Android Studio project to include source code and how to structure such a project?

or

Can you tell me what the message means and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Found this: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Dependencies-Android-Libraries-and-Multi-project-setup

Comment: The link was helpful, but doesn't quite look right in the section about Multi project setup. Instead I tried menu "File | New | Import Module...", selected the source directory and it copied some things from the folder where the source project is into a folder at the root of my project. This contradicts the project structure stated in the link above for tools.android.com... Also, I don't think it should copy anything since that project is where the source lives and needs to be debugged, so this may not be what I want.

Comment: Also needed to add a dependency to the library because my project was not compiling.